# PhantomJS error handling

Tags: javascript, exception, phantomjs

I'm having a hard time understanding how PhantomJS handles errors.

I have a locally installed Apache server running (xampp), and when I manually visit "http://localhost/" I get the "It Works!" page.

As a test, I wrote a small file (called forceError.js) that purposely causes an unchecked exception:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    url = 'http://localhost/';

page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
  console.log("page.onError");
  var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];
  if (trace && trace.length) {
    msgStack.push('TRACE:');
    trace.forEach(function(t) {
      msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function +'")' : ''));
    });
  }
  console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
};

phantom.onError = function(msg, trace) {
  console.log("phantom.onError");
  var msgStack = ['PHANTOM ERROR: ' + msg];
  if (trace && trace.length) {
    msgStack.push('TRACE:');
    trace.forEach(function(t) {
      msgStack.push(' -> ' + (t.file || t.sourceURL) + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function ' + t.function +')' : ''));
    });
  }
  console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
  phantom.exit(1);
};

page.open(url, function (status) {
    console.log("status: " + status);

    // an undefined function
    thisShouldForceAnError();
});
```

When I run this using:

```
phantomjs.exe forceError.js
```

First I get "status: success" and then the process just hangs. I don't see either page.onError or phantom.onError being invoked.

Is there some property or something I need to turn on to get general error handling?

I'm on Windows 7, PhantomJS version 2.0.0, and running this in my "git bash" shell.

Comment: Might be better as an issue on GitHub. Seems like a bug in PhantomJS 2.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Good idea: https://github.com/lichunqiang/lichunqiang.github.io/issues/13

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13403

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tested on MacOS and experienced exactly the same behaviour, which indeed is a bit unintuitive and most likely just a bug. The weird thing is that, if you call *an undefined function* from the top most scope `phantom.onError` is invoked correctly<sup>1</sup>.

As a workaround you can just wrap body of the `open` callback with a `try/catch`. Hopefully it will do the job.

Just to clarify: `page.onError` is invoked if an error occurred while executing code of the requested page - not the phantom script itself. 
I have been relying on `page.onError` for a while now and it seems to work pretty stable. (Although some errors only occur in phantomjs engine, but not in *regular* browsers.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually: `"phantom.onError"` gets printed on the console infinitely as `console.error` is not supported by phantomjs.

Comment: Try `return true;` on the `page.onError`

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer was very helpful, but I'll supplement it with a code sample.

```
page.open("https://www.google.com/", function (status) {
    try {
        if (status !== "success") {
            console.log("Unable to access network");
        } else {
            //do some stuff with the DOM
        }        
    } catch (ex) {
        var fullMessage = "\nJAVASCRIPT EXCEPTION";
        fullMessage += "\nMESSAGE: " + ex.toString();
        for (var p in ex) {
            fullMessage += "\n" + p.toUpperCase() + ": " + ex[p];
        }
        console.log(fullMessage);
    }
});
```

Output will look similar to this screen snip:
[image: Output]

**UPDATE:**
This appears to be a bug specifically with `page.open`. I noticed that `phantom.onError` was catching things from callbacks, just not directly inside `page.open`. Here is another possible workaround. This at least allows you to have all the error handling code in one spot instead of having a bunch of try/catches. NOTE: You still need `page.onError` for things inside `page.evaluate`.

```
page.open(genericSignInPageUrl, function (status) {
    setTimeout(function () { //hack for page.open not hooking into phantom.onError
        if (status !== "success") {
            throw new Error("Unable to access network");
        }
        //do some stuff
    }, 0);
});
```

When actually doing things with the page, I've started using this to make sure the element I am looking for is there. Since my code is in a callback, the `onError` methods work fine. Code for the `waitFor` method is here:
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js

```
page.open(genericSignInPageUrl, function () {
    waitFor(function () {
        return page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.getElementById("idOfElementToIndicatePageLoaded");
        });
    }, function () {
        //do some stuff with the page
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your app hangs because it looks there is a loop when you call `console.error` within `phantom.onError`. Check this: [Phantomjs v2, consume huge memory+cpu, after throwing exception.](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13707)